# Javascript Firefox and open in a tab / middle click options

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have some graphs created with the Javascript library Protovis. Underneath this works by rendering out a bunch of SVG stuff.

One of the things I need to support is clicking on the graph to open a page with the details of the datapoint that was clicked on.

Currently I'm doing this by registering for "click" events in Protovis then detecting if it was a left or middle mouse button and dispatching with window.location.href = datalink; or window.open(datalink); respectively.

All of which works beautifully... in Chrome or Safari.

In Firefox the middle mouse button doesn't raise a click event.

Is there some extra something I need to capture middle click events in Firefox? or is it just not possible?

Is there some way I could get open in new tab into the right click menu?

P.S. Firefox extensions aren't a good solution, I can't really force an extension on all my users.

Comment: Whether links open in a new window or tab are a user preference. How a user indicates to their browser to open the link is up to the user based on browser UI - they might use ctrl + click to open in a new window, then have preferences to make new windows open in a tab and not focus on them. Apple users can use command key + click, or two finger tap to get a context menu and select "open in new window" with preferencs set to open in a new tab. Bottom line: let the user work out where to open windows and how to do it.

Comment: @RobG In a sense you have the essence of my problem, what do I have to do in my javascript so firefox will provide the option of opening it in a new tab to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "onmousedown" instead of "onclick".

Comment: That's interesting, mouse down is being handled by the protovis pan and scale helpers, I handn't thought to test to see if middle click was going down there. It is, now I just need to figure out how to distinguish between clicks and drags.

Comment: Thanks, replacing click with mouseup did it, along with my usual ignoring the event if we just had a pan or scale callback.